# Xcode "Import Localisations..." turns newline (\n) into actual newlines and breaks Localisable.string file

Tags: xcode, localization

In Xcode 10.1, when I export localizations via `Editor -> Export For Localization...` and then try to import the exported `.xliff` file via `Editor -> Import Localizations...`, a translation that contains multiple consecutive newline characters (`\n`) are turned into actual newlines and will then break the `Localizable.strings` file.

For example,

`"my-key" : "Hello\n\nThis is an example";`

turns into this

```
"my-key" : "Hello

This is an example";
```

**How can I avoid the newlines when importing localizations in Xcode?**

Comment: I have the same problem and I am still looking for a solution...